# CImage::Load can't load an image

Tags: c++, image

I write code as direction on MSDN, but it doesn't work. It can't load an image and save an image as bmp.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "atlimage.h"
#include "cstdio"
#include "fstream"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CImage m_image1;
    CImage m_image2;

    char *srcFile = "C:\\Users\\TYZRPVX\\Desktop\\test.jpg";
    const char *tarFile = "C:\\Users\\TYZRPVX\\Desktop\\testBmp.bmp";
    FILE *tar;
    fopen_s(&tar, tarFile, "w");
    m_image1.Load((LPCTSTR)(srcFile));
    //m_image1.Save(_T("C:\\Users\\TYZRPVX\\Desktop\\testBmp.bmp"));
    m_image1.Save(_T("C:\\Users\\TYZRPVX\\Desktop"),Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Try this:  `m_image1.Save(_T("C:\\Users\\TYZRPVX\\Desktop\\test.bmp"),Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);` Output file name in your code is incorrect. BTW, why do you need `FILE*` variable here? Seems to be unrelated.

Comment: What is that C or C++, please decide. For the moment it seems to be neither.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably compiling with Unicode enabled which the default when creating a new project in Visual Studio. This makes your cast to `LPCTSTR` incorrect. Use wide character strings for your filenames and drop the cast.

```
const wchar_t *srcFile = L"C:\\Users\\TYZRPVX\\Desktop\\test.jpg";
const wchar_t *bmpFile = L"C:\\Users\\TYZRPVX\\Desktop\\testBmp.bmp";


m_image1.Load(srcFile);
m_image1.Save(bmpFile, Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);
```